# Regex remove leading zeros if string is number

Tags: regex, substring, leading-zero

How can I remove leading zeros if the input is a number and otherwise not?

Specific scenario:
I am only interested in the last 10 characters of the input. If this substring is consisting only of numbers, I want to remove the leading zeros. Otherwise, so if there is a word character or a special character, I need this whole substring.

Example 1

input: aaaa000002d111

expected: 000002d111 (because of the 'd' in the substring)

---

Example 2

input: aaaa0000011111

expected: 11111

I managed to remove the leading zeros with `0*(.{0,10})$` but how do I proceed in case any non-digit is included?

If possible, it would be perfect, if this expected substring is in group 1 of the match.

Comment: Why is the expected result in the first case `000002d111` and not e.g. `111` or `d111`? What separates the `a`:s from the rest?

Comment: Only the last 10 characters should be considered.The a's are always a 4 characters long prefix string, that should be ignored. 
Basically speaking, if the substring is a number, I want the leading zeros be removed. Otherwise if the substring is a string, I want all 10 characters.

Comment: which language you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.{4}(?:0*([1-9]{1,10}|\w{10}))$`

skip the first 4 chars then search for either 10 digits (excluding any leading zeros) or the last 10 characters if not all digits. Both return in Group 1

see [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dzcD4m/2)

**UPDATE**

as per comments, changed the regex to allow `0` within the digits (after the first non-zero digit)

`.{4}(?:0*([1-9]\d{1,9}|\w{10}))$`

see [updated demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dzcD4m/3)

Comment: This is almost it. But his {code}aaaa0000011011{code} one doesn't work. I would expect to get {code}11011{code} as a result, but I get {code}0000011011{code}.

Comment: @BenTreeser Strange. When you look at the provided demo that gives the outcome you're after. What flavour of regex are you using?

Comment: I use the same regex flavour as you. In your example demo link, just try to replace the last 1 digit with 0. If you do so, leading zeros reappear.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
(?=.{10}$)0*?([1-9][0-9]{0,9}|(?![0-9]*$).*)$
```

or

```
(?=.{10}$)0*?([1-9][0-9]{0,9}|.*[^0-9].*)$
```

First check that we are parsing the last 10 characters (`(?=.{10}$)`).

Then lazily search for consecutive 0s, followed by a non-0 digit and other (at most 9) digits, or keep everything if there is at least a non-digit character.

In both the cases the output is stored in group 1, as required. [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/DJEYGc/1).

Comment: This does not work for example 2. Expected: 11111, but result: 0000011111

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you can try this.

```
cat a |perl -npe 's/^[a-z]+[0]+([1-9][0-9]+)$|^[a-z]+([0]+[\d]+\w\d+)$/\1\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way

Find `(?=\d{10}$)0*(\d+)$`
Replace `$1`

Says remove leading zeros of last 10 digits.
Note that if the last 10 digits are all 0's, it will leave 1 behind.

Also, the assertion fixes the match position to the last 10 characters
so no need to worry about ranges after that.

Formatted

```
 (?= \d{10} $ )        # Assert last 10 are digits
 0*                    # Leading 0's
 ( \d+ )               # (1), The rest
 $                     # EOS
```